# How to add a search icon to a search bar?

Tags: html, css

I've created a search bar and am looking to add a non-functional magnifying glass icon to it on the far left. For this, I use an icon imported from the web in my html file. Here is my code for the icon:

```html
<div class="icon">
   <i class="fas fa-search"></i> <!--html file -->
</div>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family-Poppins');


.icon {
    height: 55px; /* css file*/
    width: 55px; 
    line-height: 55px; 
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

and the one for the search bar:

```css
input {    
    width: 570px;
     ...
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
```

When I open my file in a browser, the icon is not contained in the search bar and is instead on the far right of the page.

Comment: Could you share the HTML that contains the input?

Comment: The `.icon` is positioned absolutely with a distance of `0px` to the right side. If this is not what you want, remove `position: absolute`, `top: 0`, and `right: 0`. The `position: absolute` rule is also the reason why the icon is not contained in the search bar (it's not in the flow of the page anymore).

Answer (score 1):

i wish this will help u!!

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" />
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family-Poppins");
.search {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

.search input {
  padding: 5px 22px 5px 2px;
}
```

and u can change what u want with css

Answer (score 0):

The `.icon` is positioned absolutely with a distance of `0px` to the right side. If this is not what you want, remove `position: absolute`, `top: 0`, and `right: 0`. The `position: absolute` rule is also the reason why the icon is not contained in the search bar (it's not in the flow of the page anymore).

I would do something like this (the icon is a `div` with blue background for demonstration purposes):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family-Poppins');

.search-bar {
    display: flex;
}

.icon {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px; 
    line-height: 55px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #0000EE;
   
}

input {    
    width: 570px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**hello**

You can use fontawesome.
Add the following link to your head section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css">
</link>
```

Then give the desired tag the following class and it's done.

```
class="fas fa-search"
```